# How to implement CDC in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cdc, cassandra-cli, change-data-capture

I am trying to use CDC in Cassandra tried using incremental backup as mentioned in this [link](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/cassandra-bulk-cdc-extract) but the format of SSTables is very weired for the composite keys.Is there any way to implement CDC in cassandra.
Any pointers will be very useful.

Comment: Did you try following http://architects.dzone.com/articles/cassandra-bulk-cdc-extract?

Comment: This is the same link that I have provided in Question.But I cant able to parse SSTable because it is different for composite keys as compared to single PK using sstable2json utility

Comment: Ah, sorry. Did sstable2json generate any json? Or any error messages? If so, please share.

Comment: sstable2json generates the json but for table with only one PK its gives different result and for composite key it generates different  json.SO parsing is very difficult.Also can we load these incremental SSTable to some other table if yes then what will be its schema.Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: You need to share the complete info in the question - what you tried, how it failed. When you say that parsing the json is "very difficult" you should show (in the question) what you did to parse it and the problem you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available now from Cassandra 3.8

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8844